# Claim: $a$ has $90 \% $ primes less than $n$ If $n!= 2^s \times a \times b $ and $\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor = 2^{s-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

**Description:** We can write, $n!= 2^s  \times a \times b \cdots (1)$

where $gcd(a,b)=1$ and $2^{s+1} \nmid  n!$  .**It is given that,**   $\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor = 2^{s-2}$.

**Claim:** If $n!= 2^s  \times a \times b $ and  $\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor = 2^{s-2}$, then $a$ has $90 \% $ primes less than $n$ as factor.

**Proof:**
Here,  $\nu_ p(n)$ denotes the p-adic valuation of $n$ and $s_p(n)$  denotes the sum of the standard base-p digits of $n$, so,
$\nu _{p}(n!)={\frac {n-s_{p}(n)}{p-1}}$  ($\textit{Legendre's formula}$). For $p = 2 $, we obtain $\nu _{2}(n!)= n-s_{2}(n)$, where $s_{2}(n) $ is the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $n$. The number of primes less than $n$ is denoted by $\pi(n)$. By $\textit{Prime  Number Theorem}$, $\pi(n)\approx  \frac{n}{\log n}$.

Since,  $\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor = 2^{s-2} $

$\implies \log_2(a )-\log_2(b)= \log_2 (2)^{s-2}$ [ignoring a quantity $<1$ on R.H.S]

$ \implies  \log_2(a )-\log_2(b )=n- s_2(n)-2$

$ \implies  \sum_{p \mid a}\log_2( p ^{\nu _{p}(n!)})-\sum_{q \mid b}\log_2( q ^{\nu _{q}(n!)})=n- s_2(n)-2 \dots (2)$

Equation $(2)$ implies that,

$\sum_{p \mid a}\log_2( p ^{\nu _{p}(n!)})-\sum_{q \mid b}\log_2( q ^{\nu _{q}(n!)}) >0  \cdots  (3)$

Now, we consider the smallest prime factor, $p_0$ of $a$ and the biggest prime factor$q_0$ of $b$. Note, $a$ has $i$ distinct prime factors,  $b$ has $j$ prime factors and $ i+j = \pi(n)-1\approx \frac{n}{\log n}-1$.  Since,

$\sum_{p \mid a}\log_2( p ^{\nu _{p}(n!)}) < (\log_2(p_0 ^{\nu _{p_0}(n!)}) ) \times i$ 
and,

$\sum_{q \mid b}\log_2( q ^{\nu _{q}(n!)}) >(\log_2( q_0^{\nu _{q_0}(n!)}) ) \times j$  (See [1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin7rSRyLHOAhUGtI8KHUtqD_wQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.wlu.edu%2F~baczkowskid%2Fthesis%2Fthesis.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFVrY7Gu14cNwp9gUNPjUWBEQ-2OQ&sig2=CEkAP_2zkhfcIs0N5gtw8g), Theorem 3.9 on page 7), so-

$(\log_2( p_0 ^{\nu _{p_0}(n!)}) ) \times i-(\log_2(q_0^{\nu _{q_0}(n!)}) ) \times j>\sum_{p \mid a}\log_2( p ^{\nu _{p}(n!)})-\sum_{q \mid b}\log_2(q ^{\nu _{q}(n!)})  \cdots (4) $

$\implies (\log_2(p_0 ^{\nu _{p_0}(n!)}) ) \times i-(\log_2( q_0 ^{\nu _{q_0}(n!)}) ) \times j>0$

$\implies i \times \log_2( p_0 ^{\nu _{p_0}(n!)}) > j \times \log_2( q_0 ^{\nu _{q_0}(n!)} )$

$\implies i > j  \times \frac{ \log_2( q_0 ^{\nu _{q_0}(n!)}) }{\log_2( p_0 ^{\nu _{p_0}(n!)}) }$

Let, $T=\frac{ \log_2( q_0 ^{\nu _{q_0}(n!)}) }{\log_2(p_0 ^{\nu _{p_0}(n!)}) }$.

$\therefore i > (\pi(n)-1-i)  \times T$

$\implies i > T \times (\pi(n) -1)- T \times i \implies i> \frac{T}{(1+T)} \times (\pi(n) -1)\cdots (5)$

If $  \frac{T}{(1+T)}  \approx 0.9$ so,  $i> 0.9 \times (\pi(n)-1)$.

**Query:** Is the above proof  correct? Please, let me know if anything is inconsistent.

**Reference :**

1. [Diophantine equations involving arithmetic functions of factorials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin7rSRyLHOAhUGtI8KHUtqD_wQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.wlu.edu%2F~baczkowskid%2Fthesis%2Fthesis.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFVrY7Gu14cNwp9gUNPjUWBEQ-2OQ&sig2=CEkAP_2zkhfcIs0N5gtw8g), Daniel M. Baczkowski,  A Thesis for  Master’s of Arts, Miami University.

Comment: Related question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890178/prove-finitely-many-positive-integers-n-s-such-that-n-2s2s−2−1

Answer (score 0):

Since,  $\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor = 2^{s-2} $
$\implies \log_2(\lfloor a \rfloor)-\log_2(\lfloor b \rfloor)= \log_2 (2)^{s-2}$...
 This is certainly not correct. What happens if (for example) $a=13,b=3$?

Comment: This condition  is part of the problem. You have to prove considering this case.

Comment: Also, you are forgetting that $a \times b$ has all odd factors of  $n!$, your example does not satisfy that.

Comment: in general it is not true that $\lfloor \frac{a}{b}\rfloor=\frac{\lfloor a \rfloor }{\lfloor b\rfloor}$.

Comment: Does it matter much here?

Comment: Yes it does because what you do with $\log$ is not valid.

Comment: The difference is a quantity of less than 1, I think we can ignore that as it does not affect the main result. Note that we are taking floor of log .

Comment: It does affect the result and you are taking $\log$ of the floor not floor of the $\log$.

Comment: Could you be more specific why it affects the result ? We have $\frac{a}{b} \ge \lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor$ and hence $\log_2 a - \log_2 b \ge \log_2 (\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor) = n-s_2(n)-2>0$. Hence, shouldn't  the conclusion in (3) be unaffected ?