# Prove: Finitely many Positive Integers $n, s $ such that $n!=2^s(2^{s−2}−1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

we write, $n!= 2^{s}  \times x \cdots (1)$

Here,  $2^{s+1} \nmid  n!$. Clearly, $x$ is the number that has all odd prime factors of $n!$ . **As a condition of the problem, it is given that,**   $x=2^{s-2}-1$. Then -
$$n!= 2^{s}  \times (2^{s-2}-1) \cdots (2)$$

**Definition:**

We define, $s= (n-s_2(n))$ where  $s_{2}(n) $ is the number of $1$'s in the binary representation of $n$.

For any integer $m$ let $P(m)$ denotes the greatest prime factor of
$m$ .

**Problem:**  Prove that there are only finitely many positive integers $n, s $ such that  $$n!=2^s(2^{s−2}−1)$$

**Reference :**
A work of [Cam Stewart](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1274.pdf) (the paper has appeared in Acta Mathematica),  proving a conjecture of Erdos, Stewart shows that 
the largest prime factor of $2^n-1$ is at least 
$n \times \exp\Big( \frac{\log n}{104 \log \log n}\Big)$ ,
if $n$ is large enough.

Using this result we can say that,  for large enough $n, P(x)>n$, but by definition, all prime factors of $x$ are less than $n$ , so the number of positive integers $n, s $ should   be  finite.

**Question:** Is this argument correct? Is there a simple derivation?

**Related Post:**[$a$ has $90 \% $ primes less than $n$ If $n!= 2^s \times a \times b $ and $\lfloor{\frac{a}{b}}\rfloor = 2^{s-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887036/claim-a-has-90-primes-less-than-n-if-n-2s-times-a-times-b-and)

Thanks.

Comment: This is very closely related to an earlier question of yours, right? You should include a link here to that earlier question, and a link at the earlier question to this new one.

Comment: To me the argument looks fine. But note that Stewart's (or Schinzel's, p. 3 of the pdf) result shows $P(x) > s-2$. Hence you still need to show $s-2 \ge n$ for large $n$ (but that's not hard).

Comment: By Schinzel the largest prime divsor of $2^k-1$ is $\ge (2k+1)$ for $k \neq 4, 6, 12$. Therefore it should even be possible to find all $n,s$ satisfying $n! = 2^s(2^{s-2}-1)$.

Comment: Also related, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244504/when-the-ratio-of-two-factors-is-a-power-of-2-i-e-lfloor-fracab-rflo

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @MichaelTong , I have an argument (if u mean this post), which is given under  **Reference** ,  if you have one please, post it.

Comment: @tj_ Given that $s < n$ for all $n$, it seems hard to show that $s-2 \ge n$ for any $n$... But perhaps you meant to say $2(s-2)+1 > n$ :).

Comment: @tj_ The definition of $s$ is $n - s_2(n)$, where $s_2(n)$ is a positive integer (assuming $n>0$).  Perhaps you would care to explain how $s<n$ is "clearly wrong"?  The OP's question is relatively trivial: the fact that there exists a simpler proof of finiteness is not surprising.

Comment: @Erick: $s=n-s_2(n)<n$ yields in fact a short proof without using Stewart's theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are no such integers $n, s$. The argument is simple:

a)  $n!=2^s(2^{s-2}-1) < 2^{2s-2}$

b) $s=\nu_2(n!) = n-s_2(n) < n\,\,$ (since $n>0$),$\,\,$ i.e. $\,\,s \le n-1$

Hence $n! < 2^{2n-4}$. But this isn't possible because $16\cdot n! \ge 4^n$ for all $n \ge 1$ (induction).