# Finite number of $n, s$ if $ 2^s (2^{s-2} \pm 1)=n!$ (Prove/Disprove)

Tags: calculus, number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, alternative-proof

**Problem:**  If, $ 2^s (2^{s-2} \pm 1)=n!$ ,  prove $n, s$ are finite.

**Proof 1:**
Given, $ 2^s (2^{s-2} \pm 1)=n! \cdots (1)$

Let, $x=(2^{s-2} \pm 1)$. We know,

$\log(n!) = n \log(n)-n + O(\log(n))$ (see $[1]$ Lemma, equation $(3.4)$ on page , 53)

$\implies \log( 2^s \times x)= n \log(n)-n + O(\log(n))$
$\implies \log( 2^s) +\log(x)= n \log(n)-n + O(\log(n))$
$\implies \log(x)= n \log(n)-n + O(\log(n))- \log( 2^s) \cdots (2)$

Here, $\log( 2^s)=s \times  \log2=(n-s_2(n))  \times  \log2$ $[\because s=n-s_2(n) ]$

$\therefore \log( 2^s) <  n$, so, $n \log(n)-n + O(\log(n))- \log( 2^s) $
$> n \log(n)-n + O(\log(n))- n$.

Now, we can rewrite $(2)$ as-
$ \log(x) > n \log(n)-2n + O(\log(n))=n\times (\log(n)-2)+ O(\log(n) > C \times n $
$\therefore \log(x) > C \times \log( 2^s) \implies x > C_1 \times 2^s  \cdots (3)$.

$C, C_1$ are constants. For sufficient large value of $n$, $C>100, C_1>2$. But inequality $(3)$ contradicts $x=(2^{s-2} \pm 1)$. So, $n,s$ can not be infinite.  $\square$

$\textbf{Proof 2:} $
If  $n!=a \times 2^s$ and $a$ is the odd number, then $a\geq 2^{n-1}$ .
 Let, $P(n)$ be the proposition- $n! \geq 2^{2(n-1)}$

BASIS STEP: $P(8)$ is true as $8! > 2^{14}$.

INDUCTIVE STEP:  Assume, $P(d)$ is true $(\forall d> d_0)$, we need to show that $P(d+1)$ is true. Form $P(d)$ ,
 $d! \geq 2^{2(d-1)} \implies  4 \times d! \geq 2^{2d} $. Since, $d+1>4, \forall d>4,$ we can write-$  (d+1) > 4 \times d! \geq 2^{2d} $, so, $P(d+1)$ is  also true. The inductive step is complete.

Thus, $n! \geq 2^{2(n-1)}$. 
 But then, $a \times 2^{n-1} \geq 2^{2n-2}$ $[\because s \leq n-1]$

$\implies a  \geq 2^{2n-2-n+1}=2^{n-1}$. So, $n,s$ can not be infinite.    $\square$

**Query:** Is there any error in the above proof?
If there is an error, explain the error as an answer.
Also, if you have an alternative / correct proof, please post.

**Related Post:**  [Finitely many Positive Integers $n, s $ such that $n!=2^s(2^{s−2}−1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890178/prove-finitely-many-positive-integers-n-s-such-that-n-2s2s%E2%88%922%E2%88%921). This post has an argument for $n!=2^s(2^{s−2}−1)$ using a result of *Cameron Stewart*, whereas current post concerns with the general case $n!=2^s(2^{s−2} \pm 1)$.

**Reference:**

1. Stopple, J. , A Primer of Analytic Number Theory, Cambridge University Press.

Comment: How about showing that, for any $n\geq 5$, if $n!=2^sq$ with $s,q\in\mathbb{N}$ with $q$ odd, then $q>2^s$?  It can be shown that $s\leq n-1$, and so it suffices to prove that $2^{2(n-1)}\leq n!$ (which holds for $n\geq 7$).

Comment: @Batominovski , that is what I have done.  Your $q$ is my $x$.

Comment: Ah... Induction!